# How to pass parameters from one job to another in jenkins 2.x?

Tags: jenkins

Many of my jobs seem to have broken due to:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34873

All I want to do is pass along a version and an environment:

```
MY_VER=0.1.0
MY_ENV=STAGE
```

I've tested by adding variables to a `properties_file`, by hard-coding variables, and by any other way I can think of, but I still can't pass a simple variable.

All debian packages and jenkins plugins are up to date
ubuntu version: `Linux my-box 4.2.0-41-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:09:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

jenkins version: 2.13

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a property file as an artifact in current job.
Inject the same property file in another job as environment variables.

Comment: this is exact feature that is failing after recent jenkins updates which is the whole point of the question.